# Karaf 4.3.6 Unresolved requirements:&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.cm.json)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf-maven-plugin, apache-karaf-feature

Getting bundle exception with karaf 4.3.6.

```
        ERROR Events.Framework - FrameworkEvent ERROR
        org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.karaf.features.core [10](R 10.0): missing requirement [org.apache.karaf.features.core [10](R 10.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.cm.json)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.karaf.features.core [10](R 10.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.cm.json)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_292]
```

Comment: featuresRepositories = \
        mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/standard/4.3.6/xml/features, \
        mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/framework/4.3.6/xml/features,
Startup.properties=> mvn\:org.apache.karaf.features/org.apache.karaf.features.core/4.3.6 = 15

Comment: my `startup.properties` in Karaf 4.3.6 contains `mvn\:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.cm.json/1.0.6 = 11`

Comment: ```mvn\:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.cm.json/1.0.6=11```
added in ``startup.properties``
Getting below error
ERROR Events.Framework - FrameworkEvent ERROR
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.cm.json [10](R 10.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.cm.json [10](R 10.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.json) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.felix.cm.json [10](R 10.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.json)]
@GrzegorzGrzybek

Comment: org.apache.karaf.features.cfg
```
featuresRepositories = \
        mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/standard/4.3.6/xml/features, \
        mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/framework/4.3.6/xml/features
featuresBoot = \
        (scr/4.3.6, \
        log/4.3.6, \
        ssh/4.3.6, \
        aries-blueprint/4.3.6, \
        framework/4.3.6, \
        system/4.3.6, \
        eventadmin/4.3.6, \
        feature/4.3.6, \
        shell/4.3.6, \
        management/4.3.6, \
        http-whiteboard/4.3.6, \
        bundle/4.3.6, \
        config/4.3.6, \
        wrap/2.6.1
     
```

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek can you share startup.properties file content.

Comment: ERROR Felix - Bundle org.apache.felix.cm.json [10] Error starting mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.cm.json/1.0.6 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.cm.json [10](R 10.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.cm.json [10](R 10.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.json) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.felix.cm.json [10](R 10.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.json)])

Comment: I just checked `startup.properties` from http://archive.apache.org/dist/karaf/4.3.6/apache-karaf-4.3.6.zip - javax.json is in the bundle `mvn\:org.apache.sling/org.apache.sling.commons.johnzon/1.2.6 = 11`